MYSQL Trigger on insert setting a date condition to now if other inserted column value is true
I am trying to learn more about the triggers.
While setting up a table orders
CREATE TABLE orders
 (
 id INT unsigned not null auto_increment,
 tag INT unsigned not null,
 entered datetime default current_timestamp,
 completed boolean not null default false,
 payed boolean not null default false,
 payDate date,
 pickedUp boolean not null default false,
 pickUpDate date,
 workType enum('job0', 'job1', 'Custom') not null,
primary key (id)
 )

My goal was to set the payDate value to curdate() on the entry if the order is payed on placement and leave it empty (default) if payment has not been made
I have tried multiple phrasings for triggers but this is the final result:
CREATE TRIGGER payDate_onEnter 
 BEFORE INSERT ON orders
 FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF new.payed is TRUE then
        new.payDate := curdate();
    END IF;
 END;

MySql workbench tells me that:

new.payDate := curdate(); ->"." is not valid at this position, expecting an  identifier
final END; -> is not valid at this position, expecting an EOF ....

I checked a bunch of sites and questions, including this
please help me understand what is wrong

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/set-variable.html

@Akina I have read the article..sorry but I am not sure how this is relevant in my case. I am manipulating table columns, not variables.... for me the reference was this article https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/trigger-syntax.html and I still do not understand why the error is thrown

I am manipulating table columns, not variables.... :facepalm: Please, do not think, simply test.

Trigger not needed.
CREATE TABLE orders
 (
 id INT unsigned not null auto_increment,
 tag INT unsigned not null,
 entered datetime default current_timestamp,
 completed boolean not null default false,
 payed boolean not null default false,
 payDate date DEFAULT (CASE WHEN payed THEN CURRENT_DATE END),
 pickedUp boolean not null default false,
 pickUpDate date,
 workType enum('job0', 'job1', 'Custom') not null,
primary key (id)
 )

INSERT INTO orders (tag, payed, workType) VALUES
(1, FALSE, 1),
(2, TRUE, 2);
SELECT * FROM orders;




id
tag
entered
completed
payed
payDate
pickedUp
pickUpDate
workType




1
1
2024-11-01 16:41:10
0
0
null
0
null
job0


2
2
2024-11-01 16:41:10
0
1
2024-11-01
0
null
job1



fiddle

Thanks! I managed to get to CREATE TRIGGER payDate_onEnter   BEFORE INSERT ON orders  For each row   Set new.payDate = case when payed = 1 then curdate() else null    end;  but that then throws 'field not found' on insertion. And my bad on the "variable" terminology issue. I am not sure however how the article should've helped but that's a me problem. thx again.

@RomanSmoll but that then throws 'field not found' on insertion. Of course. .. when NEW.payed = 1 ..
